# Emacs running Org mode and Coq mode at same buffer

Tags: emacs, org-mode, coq, proof-general

- I like to use Emacs to run ProofGeneral/Coq-mode, because the interactive
  tool for proving is great.
- I like to use Emacs to run Org-mode, because is a very simple way to write
  a presentation that I can edit text while doing it.

Can I have both things at same time and at the same buffer?

My propose in doing this is to have a good way to make a presentation
about Coq where I can hide/fold bullets and execute Coq code.
What I mean by "execute Coq code" is to use the interactive tool for checking
the proof.

I think that would be a nice way to make a presentation about Coq.
But if you think that this is not a good idea, I'm open mind for nice way
to give a presentation about Coq.

Now, the problem is how to do it! I'm quite newbie to all the tools related to it and don't even know if is possible.

Comment: This webpage seems relevant: http://alan.petitepomme.net/tips/